# upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3 Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Tags: magento2, php-7, magento2.3

I am trying to upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer     
php bin/magento cache:disable     
php bin/magento maintenance:enable     
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update
```

and getting this error

> In ArtifactRepository.php line 132: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or
>   uninitialized Zip object

[image]

Comment: Is there 2.6 is already launched?! then why edit is approved?

Comment: 2.2.6 working fine and running well. when I am trying to upgrade to 2.3 ver. I am getting this error I am using PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

fixed.
I installed a fresh 2.3.0 and copy from there the composer.json and all good.